# Cocos2d making HD images

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

So I built my app out of SD images and as I understand this will look a bit blurry on a device that supports HD.

If I double the size of all my images and add "-hd", will this actually make it look better on HD devices? I mean your basically stretching the SD images, does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In common cases it would not look better. You can try to sharpen double-scaled images, maybe it will help a bit. For really nice look it's better to make HD graphics first, and then downscale images for SD.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing this because you adding duplicate resources for only small clarity.

In my view its not a good practice.

Please use HD images for retina display or if you don't want to increase the size of your app then let the SD graphics there, simply don't add HD cocos2d mange that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If I double the size of all my images and add "-hd", will this
>   actually make it look better on HD devices?

No. But your images will be using 4 times the memory.